# Insert key value - array in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am getting some values (domain names) from a _POST which I have to insert into an "Array in an Array".  The array is called `$postValues["domainrenewals"]` and the I need to create another array inside this one in the format:

domainname => 1 (where 1 is the number of years).n

My code:

```
foreach ($_POST['renewthesedomains'] as $key => $value) {

   $postValues["domainrenewals"] = array($value => "1");
}

var_dump ($postData);
```

The `var_dump` shows that only the last $key -> $value pair is being inserted into `$postValues["domainrenewals"]`

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each pass of the `foreach` loop you're redefining `$postValues["domainrenewals"]` so of course only the last one is saved... Try doing this:

```
$postValues["domainrenewals"] = array();

foreach ($_POST['renewthesedomains'] as $key => $value) {
    $postValues["domainrenewals"][$value]  = "1";
}
```

If you need to add another value to the array I'm assuming it's information of the domain, so you would do something like:

```
$postValues["domainrenewals"][$value]['your_first_value'] = "1";

// Then for your other value
$postValues["domainrenewals"][$value]['renewalpriceoverride'] = 285.00;
```

Comment: Sorry to bother again, say I need to add another pair to `$postValues["domainrenewals"]` ? For instance it appears I need to extend `$postValues["domainrenewals"][$value]  = "1";` to something like `$postValues["domainrenewals"][$value]  = "1", [renewalpriceoverride] = 285.00;` tried this but adding another to the array is a problem.

Comment: Updated the answer... please mark it as the answer (checkmark on the left) if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$postValues = array();
$arr=array();

foreach ($_POST['renewthesedomains'] as $value) {
    $arr["domainrenewals"]=$value;
    $arr["no_of_years"]=1;
    $postValues[]  = $arr;
    $arr=array();
}
```